# mysql, How to select 2 columns in 2 table?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Here's a sample mysql code I'm studying:

```
    SELECT t.name
    FROM terms AS t 
    INNER JOIN term_taxonomy AS tt
    ON tt.term_id = t.term_id 
    WHERE ......
```

The above code get column "name" in table t, I want to join column "count" in table tt , so I tried:

```
SELECT t.name, tt.count
```

This modification doesn't make any difference in results. How can I get both "name" and "coount" as a result?

**problem solved** I used wpdb's get_col which can only return one column. now I changed to get_result and solved the issue. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You are saying that adding `tt.count` doesn't result in `tt.count` being part of the query result?  That makes no sense...

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Can you provide your Table create statements?

Comment: Do you want "count" or "colum" ?

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Comment: yes, adding tt.count doesn't get any extra result. I don't have table create statements. I want "count", it's a column.

Comment: where can I go to find a table schema?

Comment: @Jenny: the command is `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`

Comment: @Jenny next time use more example and show error messages, etc, to be able to help you

Comment: Please answer your own question by adding an answer and moving the solution out of the question into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved-- I was using `$wpdb->get_col` as a wrapper for the query. It's a wordpress function that returns one column only. Now I changed to `$wpdb->get_result`, things are working. Thanks for helping!